# C2100 Error: Illegal Indirection

Tags: c, pointers, function-parameter

I'm not understanding this error (C2100: illegal indirection). There are three instances I've marked-all near the bottom. I've looked online and I know it has to do with my pointers, but after 8 hours on this, I'm completely lost. There may be some other errors in here too, but I can't even tell because I can't get it to compile. Please help & I'd love an explanation I can understand so I can figure out what I'm doing wrong for the future.

```
// INCLUDE FILES
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// PROGRAM CONSTANTS
#define     MAX_MSG_LEN     81      // Maximum Message Length (Including /0 Character)

// FUNCTION PROTOTYPES
void printLength(int, int);         // Function to Validate & Print Length of String
void printString(int, char);        // Function to Print the String in Reverse
void writeToFile(int, char);

// GLOBAL VARIABLES
char input[MAX_MSG_LEN];            // Input String
int maxLength = MAX_MSG_LEN - 1;    // Actual String Length (Not Including /0 Character)
char *ptr = input;                  // Character Pointer to String
int length = 0;                     // Length of Current String
int lcv = 0;                        // Loop Control Variable


void main()
{
    FILE *ifp;
    ifp = fopen("reverseString.txt", "w");

    printf("\n\nEnter a String Between 1 and %d Characters: ", maxLength);  // Prompts User to Enter a String Less Than 80
    gets(input);        // Receives the Inputted String from the User   

    length = strlen(input);     // Counts the Length of the Inputted String & Assigns the Number to the "length" Variable

    printLength(length, maxLength);
    printString(length, *ptr);
    writeToFile(length, *ptr);
}

void printLength(int length, int maxLength)
{
    if(length > maxLength)
    {
        printf("\n\nThe Maximum Length of %d Characters was Exceeded!", maxLength);
        printf("\nProgram Terminated...\n\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    printf("\n\nThe Length of the Input String was: %d\n", length);     // Prints the Length of the Inputted String
}

void printString(int length, char ptr)
{   
    for(; lcv < length; lcv++)
    {
        ptr++;
    }

    length = lcv;
    printf("\nThe String in Reverse: ");

    for(ptr--; length > 0; length--)
    {
        printf("%c", *ptr);     // HERE IS ONE INSTANCE OF C2100
        *ptr--;                 // HERE IS ONE INSTANCE OF C2100
    }

    printf("\n\n");
    return;
}

void writeToFile(int length, char ptr)
{
    FILE *ifp;
    ifp = fopen("reverseString.txt", "w");
    fprintf(ifp, "%c", *ptr);   // HERE IS ONE INSTANCE OF C2100
    fclose(ifp);
}
```

Comment: When you fix the error in `printString` then note that you don't really need the first loop, you can just do `ptr += length`. You also don't need the assignment to `length`, and because of that you don't need the global variable `lcv` (which is good, global variables should be avoided).

Comment: You are sending the content of ptr from the main, which is basically the string (`char* ptr`). Your function accepts it as a single character( `char ptr` ) and then your logic tries to get the content of the character in variable ptr ( `*ptr`). No wonder it fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, your syntax is wrong. You need to change the declaration and definition(s)

```
  void printString(int, char);
```

to

```
  void printString(int, char*);
```

and call it like

```
 printString(length, ptr);
```

Same goes for `writeToFile()` function.

Otherwise, with the present code, in `printString()` and `writeToFile()` functions, with a definition like `char ptr`, `ptr` is not a pointer type that you can dereference.

That said,

- Never use `gets()`, it suffers from buffer overflow issues, use [`fgets()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) instead.
- Always check the return value from `fopen()` before using the returned pointer to ensure the success of the call.
- To conform to the standards, `void main()` should be `int main(void)`, at least.

Comment: Works great now! Thanks for explaining as well - I was pretty lost!

Comment: @musikluver2003 Welcome :)

Comment: `void main()` is allowed by the standard in many cases, there are not many restrictions of main's format at all, as far as the standard goes. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31263079/584518). For example, Visual Studio allows `void main()` as impl. defined behavior and that's fine because they have documented it. Just note that it is the compiler that decides the format of main, not the programmer.

Comment: @Lundin thanks sir, I know of that post already. Just for most of the cases, the hosted environment, `int main(void)` seems suitable, in case we don't intend to use command line args. `void main()` is also acceptable, but `int main(void)` is preferred. Please correct me if i'm wrong. thanks

Comment: @SouravGhosh There's no preference. C99 and C11 just say "or otherwise in some implementation-defined manner". But of course if you write a program which relies on an implementation-defined form of main, the program will not be portable. As for freestanding systems (which the OP may very well be), `void main()` is so very common that it is in practice always portable.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to compile your code on DevC++ IDE and I found out 3 issues with ur code. I would list down as follows.

1) Try changing the declarations of functions `printString()` and `writeToFile()` as Saurav Ghosh suggested.

2) include `stdlib.h` header to support `exit()` function as the definition of `exit()` is avaliable in `stdlib.h`

3)Change `void main(){/* your code*/}` to `int main(){/* your code */}`

I did the above changes and it successfully compiled on my machine.